# Creating Composite Components in Angular

Tags: angular

I want to create a `Angular` generic composite component which is composed of bunch of input fields which could be used inside multiple components across application.

For Example:
Consider a USER DETAIL component which has following Fields,

- Email - InputText Field
- Gender-Radio button.
- Age Group - A Dropdown
- Description - A Text Area.

I want to include this `USER DETAIL` component in multiple components as below:

[image]

From Conventional wisdom I can say, that I just include `<app-userdetails>` in multiple components.

But how Do I Handle the submitted `FormGroupData`? 
I mean how do I get the data from `UserDetail` when its included in another component like `CreateEmployee`?

I am not sure if I explained the above scenario properly, please point me to any web-examples or existing questions about this.

Comment: Have you looked at https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction ?

Comment: You create the form in each parent component and then use an `@Input()`  in the User details component with the form you created in the parent.

Comment: Is may typical case where you need @Output decorator and push onModelChange any new data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, to your child components you can pass `form` and **add/remove** controls to him.

**Parent component template**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form)" #form="ngForm">
        <a-comp [prop1]="name" [form]=form></a-comp>

      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

**Some child component:**

```
// a comp
@Component({
  selector: 'a-comp',
  template: `
    <input [(ngModel)]="prop1"  name="name2" #myControl="ngModel"/>
    `

})
export class AComponent {
  @Input() form: NgForm;
  @Input() prop1 = 'Angular 5';

  @ViewChild('myControl') myControl: NgModel;

  ngOnInit() {
    //console.log(this.form, this.myControl);
    this.form.addControl(this.myControl);


  }
}
```

[CODE EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3a85tq)

Passing `@Input` to childs isn't necessary. But child components need to know about `form`.

**2. Easiest way**. By using power of `DI`

**Child-component. In your case UserDetails:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'a-comp',
  viewProviders: [{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm }],
  template: `
      <input [(ngModel)]="prop1"  name="prop1"/>
      <input [(ngModel)]="prop2"  name="prop2"/>
    `

})
export class AComponent {
  prop1 = 'Hello';
  prop2 = 'World';

  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

As you can see in `@Component` decorators we set `viewProviders`. So when requiring `ControlContainer` we say to `useExisting: NgForm`. By Angular `DI` system it will go up to find first parent `NgForm`.

> ViewProviders = Defines the set of injectable objects that are visible
>   to its view DOM children.

...

> You maybe can ask: By `DI` mechanism it should search provider up to
>   root, but why it doesn't go up in hirearchy and find parent `NgForm`?

**[Constuctor](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5298b2bda34a8766b28c8425e447f94598b23901/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L163) of `ngModel`:**

```
 constructor(@Optional() @Host() parent: ControlContainer,
              @Optional() @Self() @Inject(NG_VALIDATORS) validators: Array<Validator|ValidatorFn>,
              @Optional() @Self() @Inject(NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS) asyncValidators: Array<AsyncValidator|AsyncValidatorFn>,
              @Optional() @Self() @Inject(NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR)
              valueAccessors: ControlValueAccessor[]) {
...
```

Pay attention to `@Optional() @Host() parent: ControlContainer`. It's @Optional and @Host().

> **@Host** - Specifies that an injector should retrieve a dependency from
>   any injector until reaching the host element of the current component.

So, here `@Host()` decorators restrics the `ngModel` to search only up to `host` component where `ngModel` is allocated.

[NgModel constructor](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5298b2bda34a8766b28c8425e447f94598b23901/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L163)

By this approach no need create `@Input` binding in child components to get parent `NgForm` and add NgModels controls manually.

[StackBlitz EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-get-parent-form)

Comment: @Kishor Prakash, updated answer. Added simple way to solve this

Comment: Totally made my day! Thanks for the detailed explanation.