# How to use @Input and @Output decorators to build a composite form in Angular

Tags: angular, primeng

I am working on an application using `angular` version `5`.

Here I have to create an input form to create a `Consumer` data. Where each `Consumer` is composed of other different data whose forms will be different.

i.e, My `Consumer.ts` will look like this:

```
export class Consumer{
    public detailsOfUser: UserDetail;
    public vehicles: Vehicle[];
    public dependets: Dependents[];
    ....
}
```

So rather ethan combining all the fields in one form I decided to build this as different `Components` and call them whenever I need.

My Idea is when user try a vehicle he will click on a button and a popup appears with Input fields for vehicle.

Also It allows to me add `Vehicle` on different components too.

Here is a pictorial representation:
[image]

How do I achieve this? 
I Mean how do I collect data from these individual components add them to `Consumer` component?

Please point me to any questions if its been discussed already.

I am using `Angular5` and `PrimeNG` as a component suite.

Comment: you can implement the ControlValueAccessor interface and use your child components like another formfield

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating Composite Components in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49488324/creating-composite-components-in-angular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on right track. The way to achieve what you want is through `Input` and `Output`. Your components need to work with two-way bindings.

You can read more about it [here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding---)

Let's define your inner components `Vehicle` and `User` (for simplicity I chose just two)

`vehicle.component.ts`

```
@Component({
    selector: 'vehicle',
    template: // some template here
})
export class VehicleComponent {
    @Input() model;
    @Output() modelChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

   // you need to trigger this method somehow,
   // the logic inside this component is yours to implement
   onModelChange() {
        this.modelChange.emit(this.model);
   }

}
```

`user.component.ts`

```
@Component({
    selector: 'user',
    template: // some template here
})
export class UserComponent {
    @Input() model;
    @Output() modelChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

   // same thing here
   onModelChange() {
        this.modelChange.emit(this.model);
   } 
}
```

`consumer.component.ts`

```
@Component({
    selector: 'consumer',
    template: `
         <vehicle [(model)]="vehicleModel"></vehicle>
         <user [(model)]="userModel"></user>
         <button (click)="submit($event)">Submit</button>
    `
})
export class ConsumerComponent {
    vehicleModel;
    userModel;

    submit(event) {
        // here you can use vehicleModel and userModel 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Really grateful for quick reply. One Quick question tho, `model` in `VehicleComponent ` and `UserComponent ` are instances of `Vehicle.ts` and `User.ts ` correspondingly right?

Comment: Exactly. You can name them any way you want (let's say `x`). If you want to access them in a two-way fashion, you need to create an Output called `xChange` and emit some values from somewhere :).

Comment: Ok great. Thanks.
Let try out an small example and see if it works.