# reuse child components and emit boolean to parent component

Tags: angular

I feel close but not so sure anymore. Perhaps doing it wrong entirely. Basically, user registration happens from three areas in the application. As such, I decided to create a separate component for a user with its own validation. That component would emit true or false to the parent component while displaying the error messages on each form element on its own.

Child component is:

```js
export class UserRegistrationComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input('group')

    @Output() userFormIsValid = new EventEmitter<boolean>(); 

    first_name:FormControl;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.first_name = new FormControl('', [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.minLength(3),
            Validators.maxLength(30),
            Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z ]+$')
        ]);
    }

    onChanges(): void {
        this.userFormIsValid.emit(this.first_name.valid)
    }
}
```

the template:

```html
<input type="text" [formControl]="first_name" (input)="onChanges()" class="form-control"/>
<div class="alert" *ngIf="!first_name.valid && first_name.touched">
    First name must be at least 3 alaphabets long
</div>
```

My parent component:

```js
user_form_is_valid:boolean = false;

//the form
this.rForm = fb.group({
    'user': this.fb.group({ first_name: '' }),
    'avatar': [null, []],
    'client_name': [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z ]+$')]]
});

emittedUserFormValidStatus($event) {
    //user-registration componenet emitts if the form is ok or not.
    this.user_form_is_valid = false;

    if ($event && $event != null) {
        this.user_form_is_valid = $event;
    }
}
```

The Template:

```html
<app-user-registration (userFormIsValid)="emittedUserFormValidStatus($event)" ></app-user-registration>

<!--Other business related elements/form controls goes here-->

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register New Client" [disabled]="!rForm.valid || !user_form_is_valid">
```

The issue now is...validation is working fine. But when I submit value, the values of the child component are not passed. I tried then:

```html
<app-user-registration (userFormIsValid)="emittedUserFormValidStatus($event)" [group]="rForm.controls.user"></app-user-registration>
```

But it can't compile saying the this.userFormIsValid.emit is not a function.

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49488324/creating-composite-components-in-angular/49488874#49488874

Comment: @Yerkon I wish i could totally high-5 you right now. Led me to the solution without so much change and simplifying it all the way. Thanks.

Comment: Happy to help. It's really simplifies reusing components in `forms`. Also, special thanks to @yurzui. Also check his article [angular-nested-template-driven-form](https://medium.com/@a.yurich.zuev/angular-nested-template-driven-form-4a3de2042475)